# "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested" while using app.use(cors())

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I'm trying to set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" on my server side by adding the cors() as down below on my code, but It's not working at all and returns this error: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested" on front-end side's fetch!

what's the problem? what am I doing wrong?!

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var expressValidator = require("express-validator");
var cors = require("cors");
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var path = require("path");
var config = require("./config");

app.use(cors());
// app.options('*', cors()); // I also tested this one

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(expressValidator());


var port = process.env.PORT || 1111;

var helmet = require('helmet')
app.use(helmet())
const frameguard = require('frameguard')
app.use(frameguard())
const xssFilter = require('x-xss-protection')
app.use(xssFilter())
const ienoopen = require('ienoopen')
app.use(ienoopen())
const nosniff = require('dont-sniff-mimetype')
app.use(nosniff())
app.disable('x-powered-by')

const db = require('./config').mongoURI

app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true })

app.set("superSecret", config.secret);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.use(require('./controller/v1'));


server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("⚙️ ✅ Server is running on port 1111 ✅ ⚙️");
});
```

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? Is it 2OO OK or is it instead a 4xx or 5xx error response?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I find the bug in my code. It was just a mistake about server's URL in my config file. But I'm wondered why it was throwing an error related to Access-Control-Allow-Origin!

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is typo and it is not answer for your main question but you are configuring bodyParser 2 times + helmet already has anti-xss and mime type sniffing technique and that modules will only slow down performance speed (of course if you trust helmet, otherwise you can delete that modules)

Answer (score -2):

Content-Types that require a CORS pre-flight request (the OPTIONS call) are any Content-Type except the following:

1. application/x-www-form-urlencoded
2. multipart/form-data
3. text/plain

Here we need to add Access control header.

Below code will catch all the requests of the method type OPTIONS and send back access-control-headers.

On your server/main/index js file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
  );
  next();
});
```

The code accepts CORS from all origins as requested.